# Grails (unsaved) == null from dynamic finder

Tags: rest, grails, grails-orm

I have simple code that overrides the `show()` method in a `RestfulController` subclass. The following code is adapted from the "[Implementing the 'show' action](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/webServices.html)" example in the Grails 2.5.4 docs.

```
def show() {
    Coupons instance = Coupons.findByCode(params.code)
    print("instance: ${instance}")

    if (instance == null) {
        render status: 404
    }
    else {
        return instance
    }
}
```

When no matching document is found in the database (MongoDB), the `print` statement indicates a `null` object as expected.

```
instance: null
```

When a matching document *is* found, the `print` statement prints the following.

```
instance: com.example.Coupons: (unsaved)
```

My question is, when a document is found, why is it coming back in this "unsaved" state? And more importantly, why is the condition `instance == null` evaluating to `true` when the object definitely exists?

Comment: variable `code` is not defined. Most likely you are looking for `params.code` I believe.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @dmahapatro. That was a typo from me trying to paraphrase the full code from my controller. I've fixed the typo now to reference `params.code`.

Comment: Can you also add `Coupons` domain class in question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @dmahapatro. I actually just discovered that the problem may have been the definition of `transients` in the domain class. I removed the `transients` and now the `show()` action is responding as desired.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was the presence of `transients` in my domain class. Removing the `transients` list from my domain class seems to have resolved the problem.